# open close price difference in pine-script

Tags: pine-script

I am a newbie in pinescript.

I am hoping for your kind help. I believe that it will be very easy for you to answer this But given that I am a newbie, I am struggling with it.

Question:

I am trying to backtest a strategy with following conditions on any forex script:

1. If the pip difference between open and close is +30 (basically a green candle with body size 30), buy.
2. If the pip difference between open and close is -30 (a red candle with body size 30), sell.

I tried the following code, but there is no uptraingle or down triangle i see on the chart. It shows no error in compiling. I am confused where I am wrong.

```
//@version=4
study("mystudy", overlay=true)

differenceGreen = (close[1] - open[1]) >= 30 //green bar with body size 30+
plotshape(series=differenceGreen, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup)

differenceRed = (open[1]- close[1]) >= 30  //red bar with body size 30+
plotshape(series=differenceRed, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown)
```

Comment: How do you measure "30"?  In ticks or in currency?

Comment: 30 to be measured in pips. For example if open is 1.18790 and close is 1.18825 (>30) then a triangle up  should appear below the bar. I will further refine the conditions but I  not sure why the code I mentioned in the question is simply not working for this basic open-close difference. I did not find any pinescript function which measure the open-close or high-low difference.  Since I am a newbie I am trying to figure out this basic part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to do this

```
//@version=4
study("mystudy", overlay=true)

differenceGreen = (close[1] - open[1]) >= 30 * syminfo.mintick //green bar with body size 30+
plotshape(series=differenceGreen, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup)

differenceRed = (open[1]- close[1]) >= 30 * syminfo.mintick //red bar with body size 30+
plotshape(series=differenceRed, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown)
```

Comment: Ок. Use the recommendations of the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).